# Jquery: Find image by width and add class

Tags: jquery, css, image, width, addclass

I have many divs with the same **class** and inside of divs contain a image:

```
<div class="card_div"> 
<img src="path" alt="name_image"> 
</div> 
<div class="card_div"> 
<img src="path" alt="name_image"> 
</div> 
<div class="card_div"> 
<img src="path" alt="name_image"> 
</div> 
<div class="card_div"> 
<img src="path" alt="name_image"> 
</div> 
.
.
.
```

I want find a img that if the image's width its less than 200px add a class only to this img less than 200px width.

For example:

```
var imgWidth = $(".card_div img").width();
if (imgWidth < 200) {
$(".card_div img").css({margin:"8px 8px 8px 17px", "background-color":"blue"});  
}
```

**But this code add the margin and background to every image divs** I can not change the divs name. Every divs have same name.

I want only add the css propierty to img that its less than < 200.

Its possible? Thank you

Comment: Sorry but I have many div with same class... Sorry for the error :D I have edited Post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML Markup that you posted **is not the best**, but using that exact markup I've setup this example of how you would achieve your desired result: http://jsfiddle.net/xFSLN/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card_div"><img src="http://placekitten.com/199/199" alt="name_image"></div> 
<div class="card_div"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="name_image"></div> 
<div class="card_div"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="name_image"></div> 
<div class="card_div"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="name_image"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.under-200 {
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 17px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('div.card_div]').find('img').each(function () {
     var $this = $(this), width = $this.width();
    if (width < 200) {
        $this.addClass('under-200');
    }
});
```

I would **highly recommend** that you change the HTML to be more valid.

1. All of your IDs should be unique
2. Don't include the '#' in your ID
3. Use Class Names when Appropriate

**UPDATED:** You updated your markup to be improved. I've updated the answer to reflect your changes.

Comment: IDs should not start with "#". And it should be unique. Add a class instead.

Comment: @vinay McHerbie was declaring markup as the OP had, I am sure that he knows this - see point 2 of his recommendations list.

Comment: @vinay, My answer was using the original markup that was provided.

Comment: @hyperrjas, I've updated my answer and the JSFiddle example to use your updated markup.

Comment: Wuauuuuuuuuuuuu @McHerbie working fine :D Thank you very much!

Comment: @McHerbie it possible center the image inside div .card_div with the new class under-200 in this case. I try center with margin: 0 auto but for me dont working fine. in html div align center... center the img inside div...

Comment: Fixed and working fine now :D I have replaced inside $this.addClass('under-200'); I have put $('div.pined_index').css("text-align","center"); Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$("div.card_div > img").filter(function() {
  return $(this).width() < 200;
).css({margin:"8px 8px 8px 17px", "background-color":"blue"});
```

Or, preferably, if you had a css class that had the necessary styling:

```
$("div.card_div > img").filter(function() {
  return $(this).width() < 200;
).addClass('cssClassHere');
```